# DDD - Domain Driven Design, which development order should be applied?

Tags: python, architecture, domain-driven-design

1 - Design my entities, ie (in python):

```
class Account:
    def __init__(name, author):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
```

2 - Design my repositories: (as interface)

```
class AccountRepository:
    def add(self, account):
        """ @type account Account """
        pass

    def find_by_name(self, name):
        pass

    def find_by_email(self, email):
        pass

    # remove, and others...
```

Now, I can go two ways:

**A:** Design and implement my domain services:

```
class SignUpService:
    def __init__(self, account_repository):
        """ @type account_repository AccountRepository """
        self._account_repository = account_repository

    def create_account(self, username, email):
        account = Account(username, email)
        self._account_repository.add(account)

    # other methods that uses the account_repository
```

**B:** Implement my Repositories Strategies:

```
class MongodbAccountRepository(AccountRepository):
    def __init__(self, mongodb_database):
        self._mongodb_database = mongodb_database

    def add(self, account):
        account_data = account.__dict__
        self._mongodb_database.accounts.insert(account_data)

    # and the other methods
```

Which is the correct order? and why? 1, 2, A, B or 1, 2, B, A?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

Firstly I'd start off with the UI, thinking about the tasks/commands users need to perform and the data involved in each task/command. This is known as a [Task-Based UI](http://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/task-based-ui/) approach.

These tasks will form a 1-1 mapping with methods provided by the Application Services (different to a Domain Service).

Then I'd design my aggregates based on these tasks & data - an optimal design would be for one task/transaction (Application Service call) only involving one aggregate. To me, this is what designing aggregates based on behavior is all about.

I only implement Domain Services where a transaction needs to change state on more than one aggregate. These Domain Services abstract any logic away from the Application Service (who's job is only to orchestrate).

Storage would come last - you can only implement storage once you know exactly what you're storing?

So my full order is:

1. UI
2. Application Service (I call it a command service)
3. Domain
4. Aggregates
5. Domain Service
6. Storage

FYI I tend to follow the principals of [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) so querying is also another 'layer' I need to consider, but I've just given the order in terms of DDD and designing aggregates.

On the subject of designing aggregates, I recommend the [these articles by Vaughn Vernon](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/)

[I also wrote a blog](http://practical-ddd.blogspot.co.uk/) regarding designing aggregates based on behavior.

Comment: I'd argue that tackling anything that is **not** your domain first in DDD, does not follow the ethos of DDD which is [placing the project's primary focus on the core domain and domain logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) and therefore [Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Domain-Driven-Design-Tackling-Complexity-Software/dp/0321125215).  Your domain is the heart of your application.  Discussing domain requirements with the domain experts will allow you to identify the requirements, contexts, objects and behavious exposed in your domain.

Answer (score 3):

My personal opinion is that one should start where the business logic is located and that is the domain. Even though you would implement one user story at the time, one should start from the domain and operations in the domain. One should also apply the same languange (ubiquitous language) in the domain.

After that is implemented and tested, rest comes naturally. You implement infrastructure concerns, application services, ui.

Answer (score 2):

On one level you've answered your own question. Your `SignUpService` is using an `AccountRepository`, so you'll need at least some repo implementation just to basic testing. On a practical level, though, you're likely to see more churn in your services as you come to grips with your domain, so that's where you'll probably need to spend more time.

So if you're looking for a rule of thumb, I'd say to first get a working repository implementation. It doesn't have to be your "production" version, but it should be able to drive the system. Then get your services and the rest of the domain correct. The domain model - not the storage layer - is where the value in DDD comes from, so get that right and let that inform your choice of storage backend, not the other way around.